# Running OWL API 5

Tags: android, owl, semantic-web, ontology, owl-api

I am trying to use OWLAPI 5.1.0 on Android v8.0 (Oreo). However, when I run the app, it crashes at OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager().
I have added the following jars to my app's gradle.build (Source of jar files - [here](https://github.com/owlcs/releases/blob/master/owlapi/5/owlapi-dependencypack-5.1.0.zip)):

```
implementation files('libs/aopalliance-1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/caffeine-2.3.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-rdf-api-0.3.0-incubating.jar')
implementation files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/guava-20.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/guice-4.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/guice-assistedinject-4.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/guice-multibindings-4.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.5.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpcore-nio-4.4.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.5.2.jar')
implementation files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar')
implementation files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
implementation files('libs/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar')
implementation files('libs/jsonld-java-0.9.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/jsr305-3.0.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/owlapi-distribution-5.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-model-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-api-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-binary-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-datatypes-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-jsonld-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-languages-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-n3-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-nquads-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-ntriples-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-rdfjson-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-rdfxml-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-trig-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-trix-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-rio-turtle-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/rdf4j-util-2.1.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar')
implementation files('libs/trove4j-3.0.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/xz-1.6.jar')
implementation files('libs/org.semanticweb.hermit-1.3.8.500.jar')
```

The app is building just fine. But on running, it crashes throwing the error below:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.create(MethodWrapper.java:34)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:231)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:252)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:203)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:275)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:144)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:123)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:349)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createInjector(OWLManager.java:104)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:44)
    at com.example.newcalculator.OwlApiSecond.creatingOntology(OwlApiSecond.java:37)
    at com.example.newcalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:256)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:149)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:23)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.create(MethodWrapper.java:34) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:25) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:231) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:252) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:203) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:69) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:275) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:144) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:123) 
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340) 
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:349) 
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104) 
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99) 
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) 
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) 
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createInjector(OWLManager.java:104) 
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:44) 
    at com.example.newcalculator.OwlApiSecond.creatingOntology(OwlApiSecond.java:37) 
    at com.example.newcalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:395)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:390)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:235)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:149) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:23) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.create(MethodWrapper.java:34) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:25) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:231) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:252) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:203) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:69) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:275) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:144) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:123) 
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340) 
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:349) 
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138) 
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104) 
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99) 
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) 
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) 
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createInjector(OWLManager.java:104) 
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:44) 
    at com.example.newcalculator.OwlApiSecond.creatingOntology(OwlApiSecond.java:37) 
    at com.example.newcalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:591)
            ... 44 more
```

I would like to know how to solve this error. I am not sure what exactly is causing it.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace does not mention which class cannot be loaded, so it's hard to tell if the problem is in Guice or in OWL-API.

However, OWLAPI 5.1.0 is fairly old. 5.1.10 is available now, as well as HermiT 1.4.3.517. I would recommend updating to these versions.

One change that might be relevant in your case is that the latest versions of OWLAPI do not use Guice any more. I have not tested them on Android, but it's worth a shot to see if the problem here is entirely in Guice or not.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was because of the Guice dependency.